# where to put c/c++ __attribute __ keyword

Tags: c, gcc

Normally `__attribute__` is put behind the declaration, but how about it with typedef.

```
typedef struct {} PKD_1 __attribute__ ((packed));
typedef struct {} __attribute__ ((packed)) PKD_2;
typedef struct {} DPCT_1 __attribute__ ((deprecated));
typedef struct {} DPCT_2 __attribute__ ((deprecated));
typedef struct {} __attribute__ ((deprecated)) DPCT_3;

DPCT_2 dpct_2;
```

I try to compile this code with clang, and got a warning like this:

```
cpp/main.cpp:1:41: warning: 'packed' attribute ignored [-Wignored-attributes]
typedef struct {} PKD_1 __attribute__ ((packed));
                                        ^
cpp/main.cpp:5:9: warning: '' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
typedef struct {} __attribute__ ((deprecated)) DPCT_3;
        ^
cpp/main.cpp:5:9: note: '' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
cpp/main.cpp:7:1: warning: 'DPCT_2' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
DPCT_2 dpct_2;
^
cpp/main.cpp:4:19: note: 'DPCT_2' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
typedef struct {} DPCT_2 __attribute__ ((deprecated));
                  ^
3 warnings generated.
```

So,
1. Why `__attribute__ ((packed))` need to be before typedef name? (PKG_1 warning.)
2. Why if I put `__attribute__ ((deprecated))` after typedef name, it only report a deprecated when I define a struct varible, but when it is put before the name `DCPT_3`, it report warning as soon as the typedef statement.

Comment: Both are answered in the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html), especially the [Common Type Attributes section](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html), when using GCC. [Clang might behave slightly differently](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html), because these are extensions, not part of standard C.